# return a default value for empty field on a django model

Tags: django

I have a model in which one field is often the blank string.  Is there a way to return (for e.g.) the string 'default' instead of that blank string for queries on that model?

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    afield = models.CharField(...)  # many rows set afield to ''
```

When I perform a query

```
o = MyModel.objects.all()
vars(o[0])
{...
'afield': ''  # afield is empty
...}
```

I would rather see

```
vars(o[0])
{...
'afield': 'default'
...}
```

Is there a way to do this?  Is there a better way to implement this than inside the model?

Notes:

- I do not want to store the string 'default'
- [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2158272/1698426) alters the database, I want to avoid that

Comment: why not store the value?  If you really don't want to, then consider creating an access function or template filter.  Answer all depends on how you use the data; so perhaps an example of how you would use `MyModel.objects.all()` after fetching it would help.

Comment: My users expect to see 'default' when a web page gets populated with this field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably much, *much*, **much** better to handle this in views as part of your logic, but you could use properties and setters to do this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    _afield = models.CharField(...)
    @property
    def afield(self):
        if self._afield:
            return self._afield
        else:
            return "default"

    @afield.setter
    def afield_setter(self,value):
        self._afield = value
```

Comment: Why do this in the views?  If I'm returning a REST response, I must go through each item in the queryset and mutate this field in my serializer.  "Fat models and thin views" seems like a good practice to me.

Comment: A REST response is still a "view" on the model, and its not "business logic". If having a default value were "business logic" you'd actually be storing it. I think there are things you aren't telling us about `afield` that would help you get a better answer.

Comment: I'm storing references to mercurial changesets.  When a changeset is not on a branch, it is on "default".  When looking at the changeset via `hg log`, the branches field is the empty string for changesets not on a branch.

Answer (score 4):

You can override [__getattribute__()](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) method:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ....
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        attr = models.Model.__getattribute__(self, name)
        if name == 'afield' and not attr:
            return 'default'
        return attr
```

Here is the usage:

```
>>> obj = MyModel()
>>> obj.afield
'default'
>>> getattr(obj, 'afield')
'default'
>>> obj.afield = 'test'
>>> obj.afield
'test'
>>> getattr(obj, 'afield')
'test'
>>> obj.afield = ''
>>> obj.afield
'default'
>>> # other properties work as usual
>>> obj.some_var = 123
>>> obj.some_var
123
```

Comment: What if there are other properties that aren't defined in `models.Model`?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr they will work as usual.  You can set/get any attribute to this class.

Comment: __getattribute__() eventually resolved to a retrieval from the database?  That sounds great.  Why was this voted down?

Comment: `__getattribute__()` is called then you get any attribute of the `MyModel` instance. And of course this is a true for a instances retrieved from the database.  The only drawback is that if you want to access the "real" value of the `afield` attribute you need to do it with a pretty peculiar way: `obj.__dict__['afield']`

Comment: great solution; however i believe a filter in the template would follow MVC principles better.

Comment: @warath-coder I agree that explicit  `{{ obj.afield|default:"default" }}` and `obj.afield or "default"` is much better design decision.  But I just answered the question :-)

Comment: I don't know how to use this approach for cases like `MyModel.objects.all().distinct('afield').values_list('afield')` which gets serialized by the Django REST Framework and then populated in a pulldown on a web page.  The blank string is displayed.

Comment: `values_list()` returns list of tuples so any manipulations with `MyModel` can't help here. You have to use `map()` or list comprehension to replace empty value with default. For example:  `map(lambda x: (x[0] or 'default',), MyModel.objects.all().distinct('afield').values_list('afield'))`