# When Django models field is empty, set value to the Default value

Tags: python, django, django-models

Whenever the user doesn't add a value, I need my Django models to replace the otherwise empty field with the value set in `default`.
My models looks like this:

```
not_before = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True, default='00:00:00')
max_num_per_day = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=0)
```

I tried every combination of `null`, `blank` and `default` but no matter what I do, the fields gets replaced by `null` instead of `'00:00:00'` and `0`.

Is there anyway I can force it to the `default` value whenever the field is empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from what I understood from your question is you just want to set it to default. you can use:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6754

don't

```
not_before = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True, default='00:00:00')
```

instead,

```
import datetime
not_before = models.TimeField(default=datetime.time(0,0))
max_num_per_day = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: That's exactly want I wanted, but now when I try, it throws me a 400 Error with `"not_before": [{"message": "This field is required.", "code": "required"}], "max_num_per_day": [{"message": "This field is required.", "code": "required"`

Comment: have you made the changes at the database level ?

Comment: Yea, I did the migrations, and I also tried it with `blank=True` just to see, but it would throw me `IntegrityError: stp_stp.not_before may not be NULL` as an error

Comment: but the default value is editable so still it can be blank if user delete the default value saved.

Comment: (1048, "Column 'username' cannot be null")

Answer (score 4):

you can set up your form  with a default function like:

```
class YourForm(forms.Form):    
.....
def clean_field(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['not_before']
        if not data:
            data = '00:00:00'
```

or write a function in your model like:

```
class Molde(models.Model):
  not_before = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True, default='00:00:00')
  def time(self):
    if self.not_before:
        return self.not_before
    else:
        return '00:00:00'
```

In this case you would call the function instead of the model field itself. You can also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290998/return-a-default-value-for-empty-field-on-a-django-model).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/) to grab the data from the user.

In this case, the solution proposed by sasuke will not work. First, you would have to set the `required` param to `False` in your form fields, so you would stop seing those "This field is required" messages. Still, you would see errors when saving the form. Even if your model instance is initialized with the default value, the form will replace it with `None`, since there is an existing field in the form matching the field in the model and its value is `None`.

My solution is to override the values in the model instance before saving them:

```
model_instance = myform.save(commit=False)
if not model_instance.not_before:
    model_instance.not_before = '00:00:00'
if not model_instance.max_num_per_day:
    model_instance.max_num_per_day = 0
model_instance.save()
```